# Issue with TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter for infragistics

Tags: infragistics, region

I am using TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter from https://compositewpfcontrib.svn.codeplex.com/svn/Trunk/src/Extensions.Infragistics/Composite.Wpf.Infragistics/CompositeWPFContrib.Composite.Wpf.Infragistics/XamDockManager/Regions/TabGroupPaneRegionAdapter.cs.

The problem I am getting with this is contentpane's Closed event executes two times which is probably due to line 'contentPane.ExecuteCommand(ContentPaneCommands.Close);' Which means when cross button was pressed and closed event was invoked first time it was still there in xamDockManager hence line "contentPane.ExecuteCommand(ContentPaneCommands.Close);" executes and invokes closed event again. Any ideas how to solve this.

Here is part of code from adapter:

```
private void OnViewsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e, IRegion region, TabGroupPane regionTarget)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            //Add content panes for each associated view. 
            foreach (object item in e.NewItems)
            {
                UIElement view = item as UIElement;

                if (view != null)
                {
                    ContentPane newContentPane = new ContentPane();
                    newContentPane.Content = item;
                    //if associated view has metadata then apply it.
                    if (view.GetTabGroupPaneMetadata() != null)
                    {
                        newContentPane.Header = (view.GetTabGroupPaneMetadata()).Header;
                    }
                    //When contentPane is closed remove the associated region 
                    newContentPane.Closed += delegate(object contentPaneSender, PaneClosedEventArgs args)
                    {
                        OnContentPaneClosed((ContentPane)contentPaneSender, args, region);
                    };


                    regionTarget.Items.Add(newContentPane);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
            {
                //Associated View has been removed => remove the associated ContentPane from XamDockManager
                XamDockManager xamDockManager = regionTarget.FindDockManager();
                IEnumerable<ContentPane> contentPanes = xamDockManager.GetPanes(PaneNavigationOrder.VisibleOrder);

                foreach (ContentPane contentPane in contentPanes)
                {
                    if (e.OldItems.Contains(contentPane.Content))
                    {
                        contentPane.Content = null;
                        contentPane.CloseAction = PaneCloseAction.RemovePane;
                        contentPane.ExecuteCommand(ContentPaneCommands.Close);
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }

    private void OnContentPaneClosed(ContentPane contentPane, PaneClosedEventArgs args, IRegion region)
    {
        object view = contentPane.Content;
        if (region.Views.Contains(view))
        {
            region.Remove(view);
        }
    }
```

Any help will be much appreciated thanks.
Imad.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you could follow the Infragistics Forum Thread regarding the very same matter here:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/73207.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There is a better region adapter for the xamDockManager available here.

http://brianlagunas.com/xamdockmanageran-updated-prism-region-adapter/